# Dates Datatype Operation

Tags: sql, oracle, date, numbers, operators

Why does this SQL statement work:

```
SELECT SYSDATE - 1 - DATE '2019-01-01' FROM DUAL
```

and this one does not work?

```
SELECT 1 - SYSDATE - DATE '2019-01-01' FROM DUAL
```

I understand that you cannot operate a number with a date, but because of this, I don't understand why the first query works.

Comment: Please don't SHOUT when posting here. Text in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read and understand, and won't get you an answer any faster. It's also rather impolite to SHOUT at people you're asking for **free help** to solve **your problem**.

Answer (score 1):

SYSDATE - 1 means one day before now. Oracle sees the attempt to substract (or add) a number to/from a date and automatically interprets the number as a full 24-hour day. That's why it works.

You cannot however reverse this: 1 - SYSDATE is meaningless in Oracle. It would have to mean "now before one day" which makes no sense. You can subtract/add numbers (days) to dates, but you cannot subtract a date from a number.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT SYSDATE - 1 - DATE '2019-01-01' FROM DUAL
```

Works because the operators are evaluated in precedence order and then, for operators of the same precedence, from left-to-right so the query is, with brackets to show the order of evaluation:

```sql
SELECT ((SYSDATE - 1) - DATE '2019-01-01') FROM DUAL
```

And the inner bracket has the types `DATE - NUMBER` which results in a `DATE` type and then substituting that into the outer bracket, it has the types `DATE - DATE` which outputs `NUMBER`; so the query works.

---

```sql
SELECT 1 - SYSDATE - DATE '2019-01-01' FROM DUAL
```

Can be rewritten with brackets showing the evaluation order of operators as:

```sql
SELECT ((1 - SYSDATE) - DATE '2019-01-01') FROM DUAL
```

Which fails because `1 - SYSDATE` is `NUMBER - DATE` which is not a valid operation.

If you want it to be syntactically correct then use brackets to change the precedence:

```sql
SELECT 1 - (SYSDATE - DATE '2019-01-01') FROM DUAL
```

Then `SYSDATE - DATE '2019-01-01'` is evaluated first and `DATE - DATE = NUMBER` and then `NUMBER - NUMBER` will work.